# How to align text in a same paragraph in left and right in primevue InlineMessage

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue, primevue

I want to align 2 texts left and right using bootstrap. I have used primevue component InlineMessage.

```
<InlineMessage severity="error" class="my-4 block align-items-center">Error Request Percentage <span class="" > 10%</span> </InlineMessage>
```

Can someone help me?

I tried to use text-align, align-items but it seems like not applying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In primevue `<InlineMessage>` component has an embedded icon. in that case, if you going to use `class = "justify-content-between"` it will be not worked as you expected.

But you will be able to do it...

```
<InlineMessage severity="success" class="block py-5 my-4">   
  <div class="" style="float:left">Total Requests</div>   
  <div class="" style="float:right">10</div>  
</InlineMessage>
```

And also parent element width should be 100%.

Comment: What do you mean by parent element. Is it the InlineMessage block?

Comment: Yes..! but there will be an inherited patent element. You can check it using browser inspect element.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to align one text to the left, and the span to the right?

First, you need to change the `block` class to `flex` so that you can use flexbox.

Then you need to use the [justify-content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) utility. You can do this with the class `justify-content-between`.

If you don't see the changes, just add the class `w-100` so that the `<InlineMessage>` element takes up 100% of the available width.

Your code would look like this:

```
<InlineMessage severity="error" class="my-4 flex justify-content-between w-100">Error Request Percentage <span style="margin-left: auto" > 10%</span> </InlineMessage>
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got  partially correct answer. I got tick in the leftside but all the "Error Request Precentage: 10%" in the rightside. I am using primevue InlineMessage

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer. can you try now?

Comment: I added a margin-left: auto style to the span.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has no `.block` css definition, you can add it yourself, for example:

`.block { display: flex; }`

And append to your inline class `justify-content-center` to center it.

If you wish to use block then define `.block { display: block; }` and append class `text-center` to center the text.

Otherwise your inline is just long as the text inside of it, and it will never align it

```css
.block { display: flex; }
.block2 { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<InlineMessage severity="error" class="my-4 block align-items-center justify-content-center">Error Request Percentage <span class="" > 10%</span> </InlineMessage>



<InlineMessage severity="error" class="my-4 block2 text-center">Error Request Percentage <span class="" > 10%</span> </InlineMessage>
```

If I understood correctly you wish to align differently inside of inline element, then you can use something like this:

```css
.block { display: flex; }
.block > span { flex: 1; text-align: right; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<InlineMessage severity="error" class="my-4 block align-items-center justify-content-left">Error Request Percentage <span class="" > 10%</span> </InlineMessage>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I doesn't work exactly as I expected. I figured it reference to you answer. My solution is in L.Raudel comment section